# Помощь в вёрстке, реализация изображений на сайте

Tags: flexbox, float, img, position, containers

Нашёл макет из открытого доступа, так как я новичок в этом деле, помогите пожалуйста как правильно реализовать данный блок с картинками... Ладно если бы просто картинки, но между ними есть связующая серая линия. Как правильно и лучше поступить? через float как то делать или ещё как то? Заранее спасибо всем кто уделил время на моq относительно наверно глупый вопрос... Всем добра!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: чередовать текст\картинка можно например с `:nth-child(even\odd)` а линия - два белых инлайн-блока  с бордером. ну или если по нормальному - SVG кривая.